# jquery get the index of a row?

Tags: jquery, indexing, row

**Even this isn't working....**

```
$("table#mytable > tbody > tr").each(function(index) {
    if($(this).attr('id','firstrow')) {
        $("input[name^=f1]").focus(function() {
            var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';
            $("tbody").append(newRow);
        });         
    } else {
        $("input[name^=f2]").focus(function() {
        var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';
        $("tbody").append(newRow);  
        });         
    }
});

<table id="mytable">
<tbody>
<!-- this is the first row, if the user clicks in f1, a new row is appended -->
<tr valign="top" id="firstrow">
    <td><input type="hidden" value="secret" name="std"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="f1[]"><label>F1</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="f3[]"><label>F2</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="f4[]"><label>F4</label></td>
</tr>

<!-- this is the new row that is append if the user clicks in f1.  From here on out, a new row is appended if the user clicks in f2 -->
<tr valign="top">
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="f2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="f1[]"><label>F1</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="f3[]"><label>F2</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="f4[]"><label>F4</label></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The html I'm working with...

```
<table id="mytable">
<tbody>
<!-- this is the first row, if the user clicks in f1, a new row is appended -->
<tr valign="top">
    <td><input type="hidden" value="secret" name="std"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="f1[]"><label>F1</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="f3[]"><label>F3</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="f4[]"><label>F4</label></td>
</tr>

<!-- this is the new row that is append if the user clicks in f1.  From here on out, a new row is appended if the user clicks in f2 -->
<tr valign="top">
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="f2[]"><label>F2</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="f1[]"><label>F1</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="f3[]"><label>F3</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="f4[]"><label>F4</label></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Yet another revision that still isn't working.  I'm not even getting the alert...

```
$("table#mytable > tbody > tr").each(function() {
        if($(this).index(0)) {
            $("input[name^=f1]").focus(function() {
            var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';
                $("tbody").append(newRow);
            });         
        } else {
            $("input[name^=f2]").focus(function() {
                                                         alert(index);
            var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';
            $("tbody").append(newRow);  
            });         
        }
    });
```

**Edit - Latest revision, but still isn't working...**

```
if($("#mytable > tbody > tr:first")) {
            $("input[name^=f1]").focus(function() {
            var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';
            $("tbody").append(newRow);
            });
    }

    if($("#mytable > tbody > tr:not(:first)")) {
            $("input[name^=f2]").focus(function() {
            var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>';
            $("tbody").append(newRow);  
            });
    }
```

I'm trying to write a function that will do something if the the row index is 0, and then something else if the row index is greater than 0.  The zero part is working, but I can't figure out the syntax for rows that have an index greater than 0.

For the tr[0] row, I'm doing this:

```
if($("#mytable > tbody > tr ").index(0)) {
```

...

I tried:

```
if($("#mytable > tbody > tr ").index() > 0 ) {
```

But, that didn't work?

Comment: What do you mean when you way **if the the row index is 0**. Do you mean if row that was clicked is 0, or do you mean that you want to loop through all the rows and do something to each based on its index, or are you trying to test if there are any rows in the table?

Comment: I just mean if it's the first row in the table, then do something, else do something else...  I edited my original code and I've tried everything suggested here.  (I'll also post yet another rev in my original post, and that isn't working either...)

Comment: Your if statement (`if($("#mytable > tbody > tr:first"))`) will always evaluate to true. jQuery always returns an object, which is always truthy. Use `.size()` or `.length` to see if the jQuery object contains any elements.

Comment: With your latest edit, change `.each(function() {` to  `.each(function(index) {` then change `if($(this).index(0))` to read `if(index === 0)`.

Comment: I think you need to make your HTML available.

Comment: I updated my answer, but the trouble is when you say **if it's the first row in the table**, we don't know what is bringing attention to the row you're interested in. If you click a row, or hover a row, or enter into an `input` in a row, then "attention" has been brought to that row. The way you're doing it, you're simply asking if there is a row. As long as at least one row exists, the answer will be yes.

Comment: Ok...  I altered the code according to Matt's comment, but it still didn't work.  Per knut, I added in the html I'm working with.  And, I'll try patrick's suggestion in just a sec...

Comment: Is it *just* the first two rows that have inputs that should receive `focus()` events? Or is this a situation where we need to loop through several rows and add events?

Comment: No, it's all of the rows.  If it's the first row, a new row is appended if the user clicks in <input name=f1>.  If it's *any* of the other rows (which will all be appended rows beyond that first one), then any time a user clicks in <input name=f2>.  I even tried giving that first row a unique id and appending based on that, but it just won't append if it's not the first row...

Comment: Another question, `$("input[name^=f1]").focus(function() {...` seems to be doing the same thing as the one for `f2`. Are they the same, or are these just simplified examples?

Comment: Simplified...  The first row doesn't actually have this input field at all...  I just edited my post to show my attempt at using the row ID instead of the index...

Comment: Events are attached when the page loads. If you dynamically add a row, you need to either bind events on it when you load it, or use jQuery's `live()` function which binds events automatically to elements that are added dynamically.

Comment: Ok, well I tried changing it to: $("table#mytable > tbody > tr").live('focus',function(index) {  and I get: $("table#mytable > tbody > tr").live is not a function

Comment: `live()` is a function, but looks like 'focus' is not supported. Sorry, didn't realize that. There's another event called 'focusin'. I updated my answer again using that. It places the event handler on the table itself, and checks to see which input got the focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#mytable").delegate('tr:gt(0) input[name^=f2]', 'focus', function () {
    $('#mytable > tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');
});
$('#mytable tr:first-child input[name^=f1]').bind('focus', function () {
    $('#mytable > tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');
});
```

One of your problems is that the remaining rows are added after the focus event was bound, which was why I've opted to use `delegate` for the rows that aren't the first row.

Answer (score 2):

To get the the first row you could use:

```
$("#mytable > tbody > tr:first")
```

More flexible is the [gt() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) (or also [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)):

```
$("#mytable > tbody > tr:gt(0)")
```

Comment: Tried this (I edited my original post so you can see what I did) and for the life of me, I can't understand why this isn't working?

Comment: What do you want exactly to do? For me it looks like you try to dynamically expand the rows if the user entered something in the last remaining row, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looping through the items:

```
$('#mytable>tbody>tr').each(
    function(index, item)
    {
        if(0 == index)
        {
            // Do something
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
);
```

Or, you could use two different objects, kinda like this:

```
var firstOne = $('#mytable>tbody>tr:first');
var otherOnes = $('#mytable>tbody>tr').filter(function(index) { return 0 < index; });
```

You can also use the `:first` pseudoclass combined with `not()`, but I'm not entirely sure how that would be written. (I'd speculate `not(:first)` after `tr`.)

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't seem to get this to work... I tried each of the suggestions you mentioned, but it's still not appending for rows with an index greater than 0.  I'm editing my original post to show the latest revision...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [first](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selectors, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var firstRow = $('table tbody tr:first');
    var others = $('table tbody tr:not(:first)');
    //do your required work with firstRow and others...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rRRYK/2/ index() works just fine check the example

Comment: That jsfiddle is pretty slick. I've really got to start using it more.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `rowIndex` property of TR (DOM Level 2) and do stuff based on it. See [here](http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/HTMLTableRowElement.html#HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex)